# How to check if there is Feb 29 in between two dates using php

Tags: php, date

How to check if there is Feb 29 in between two dates using php

```
$fromDate = strtotime($contract->from);
$toDate = strtotime($contract->to);
```

Comment: Google "check if february 29 php stackoverflow" - many hits and many possible duplicates.

Comment: Loop through each year in turn, and use the `L` format mask for date() to test if it's a leap year

Comment: @MarkBaker so, my 2nd possible dupe is a dupe.

Comment: You can't beat recursive duping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime`, `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod` is a good way to work with dates in PHP:

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2015-12-20' );
$end = new DateTime( '2016-03-10' );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {

    if(($dt->format('m') === '02') && ($dt->format('d') === '29')) {
        echo 'got date February 29th!';
    }

}
```

This script will take first date, last date and loop over the interval day by day to check for the desired date.

Comment: Work perfect that is the best solution for my needs